# Strange handlebar behaviour if condition

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have this handlebar template:

```
{{! 1st block }}
<div class="price_new">
    {{product.price_new}}
</div>
{{! end 1st block }}

{{! 2nd block }}
{{#if product.price_new}}
<div class="price_new">
    {{product.price_new}}
</div>
{{/if}}
{{! end 2nd block }}
```

The 1st block of template is rendered correctly:

```
<div class="price_new">
    2.225.000
</div>
```

But the 2nd block is not rendered, I think product.price_new is not either null, empty, undefined as it is rendered in the 1st block, it should make the if condition a true value and the 2nd block should have been rendered but the 2nd block is not rendered at all.

I tried it on tryhandlebarsjs.com with the following context: { "foo" : "bar" } and this template:

```
<div class="price_new">
{{foo}}
</div>
{{#if foo}}
<div class="price_new">
{{foo}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

The output is rendered correctly. So the question is, in the 1st template, why the 2nd block is not redered even product.price_new = "2.225.000"? Please help, thank you guys so much

Comment: Can you make the if statement something like if true just to check that if syntax/working is correct

Comment: Hi, I tried if true and if false and they both work correctly

Comment: Syntax seems fine, can you assign product.price_new to some variable before checking the condition, just a try